# Where should I put License, If I am using 3rd party library in My Android App

Tags: android, github

I am using some 3rd party libraries(e.g. https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton) in my android app from github. Which are under Apache License, Version 2.0. My question is where should I put license in my app, should it be visible to end user? Is it neccessary to add license of libaray in my app?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because licensing/legal questions are off-topic

Comment: @Zoe I have the same question but i didn't get clear answer, will you guide me?

Comment: @AwaisChorahi No. These types of questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow

Comment: @Zoe So where should i get my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, in this case, the owner of this library forgot to add the date and his name to the Apache license text file.

Basically you have to obey what the copyright owner wants you to do. This could mean that you don't need to add anything to your project. See for example the [Terms of Service](https://pixabay.com/en/service/terms/#usage) of [Pixabay](https://pixabay.com/):

> You are free to adapt and use them for commercial purposes without
>   attributing the original author or source. Although not required, a
>   link back to Pixabay is appreciated.

If the copyright owner uses a license, you have to obey what the license tells you. This could differ from license to license. In case of Apache license see [this information](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN):

> It allows you to:
>       freely download and use Apache software, in whole or in part, for personal, company internal, or commercial purposes.
>       use Apache software in packages or distributions that you create.
>
> It forbids you to:
>       redistribute any piece of Apache-originated software without proper attribution;
>       use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that the Foundation endorses your
>   distribution.
>       use any marks owned by The Apache Software Foundation in any way that might state or imply that you created the Apache software in
>   question.
>
> **It requires you to:
>       include a copy of the license in any redistribution you may make that includes Apache software.
>       provide clear attribution to The Apache Software Foundation for any distributions that include Apache software.**
>
> It does not require you to:
>       include the source of the Apache software itself, or of any modifications you may have made to it, in any redistribution you may
>   assemble that includes it.
>       submit changes that you make to the software back to the Apache Software Foundation (though such feedback is encouraged).

By the way: What I always do to be on the safe side. I have a link in my app "Legal notice" where users can see all the licenses I use. Even if I use a picture of pixabay. I also place this information there. Actually, it's the least you can do when you use work of other people for free. 
If someone forgots to add his credentials as in your case, I add his name to the license file when I place in in my app. Otherwise the license is pretty worthless.

Comment: I am using PDF library in my android app and i want to upload it on google play store. If i dont use it does google will terminate my account or reject the app? Can you please guide me how can i add license file in my app. Thank you I am waitng for your response